# Run webservice method with thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, web-services

I want to send image to web service using fallowing code.

```
public void sendImage()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("test.png"), FileMode.Open);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();

    ImageWebService servis = new ImageWebService();
    string sonuc = servis.SaveProductImage(buffer, "test.png");
    Response.Write(sonuc);
}
```

When I use this method normally, it works fine but if I use with thread like that;

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendImage));
th.Start();
```

it doesn't work and doesn't throw any error. Do anyone have any idea?
(Web service and test web page is located same server.)

Comment: could be several things. maybe the error it is throwing is being swallowed (perhaps the Response is out of context at this point). Did you follow it through in the debugger? (step through). Also, by the time the thread finished executing, the main thread has finished processing hence why you don't see any results happening. this is not a sync process but an async type of process...

Comment: When I run on visual studio, the thread works fine. Probably the problem in the ftp server settings. I made log after every step. After SaveProductImage method thread is killed by GC.

Comment: What does your code after the creating the `sendImage` thread? If it does nothing then your child thread simply being killed before it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the code that starts the `sendImage` thread:

```
Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendImage));
th.Start();
```

If after this code there is no other work, then you have a race condition in your program: the child thread tries to do work, but can be aborted in any moment, as it is background thread and do not prevent program from closing.

This problem can't be reproduced in debug mode because the VS do not optimize the code being debugged.

I suggest you to add `Task` for your code and explicitly wait for it:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => sendImage());
await task;
```

Comment: I had to resolve that problem with another solition. Because the web project use .net 3.5 framework and there isn't await code in there. This problem is very silly. Try to write any basic text with thread on asp.net web form. Thaks everybody.